# JS Smooth Scroll conflicting with Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think it's a simple (maybe very simple). But since my know in javascript is very limited, I need to ask to you guys.

I'm using this code

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 6000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

To do the smooth scroll thing. But the problem is: it also "corrupts" the tabs/accordion from Foundation. There is a way to limit the smooth scroll to only work with a class, maybe? For example:

```
<a href="#home" class="smooth"></a>
```

If so, how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

> $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')

with

> $('a[href*=#].smooth:not([href=#])')

With this code, JQuery selects all links that have the class, smooth (which is indicated in css by the .smooth)

Answer (score 0):

Now, some years later, Foundation 6 supports this out of the box:

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/smooth-scroll.html